# ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got:

Tags: python, folium

ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got: 0         39.036270
1         39.277840
2         39.086688
3         39.086688
4         39.198295
...
318012    39.150550
318013    39.113490
318014    39.288290
318015    39.036540
318016    39.140500
Name: Latitude, Length: 318017, dtype: float64.

Hi`all,

I am trying to implement the map using this dataset, but the issue is as follows``

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
# Change colours
# Create base map
Montgomery = [32.35031, -86.26321]
map = folium.Map(location = Montgomery,
                 zoom_start = 12, 
                 tiles = "CartoDB positron")

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(locations=[df.Latitude, df.Longitude]).add_to(map)
# Plot markers
for _lat, _lon, _name in zip(df.Latitude, df.Longitude, df['Crime Name1']):
    folium.CircleMarker(location = [_lat, _lon], 
                        radius = 9, 
                        fill_opacity = 0.9).add_to(marker_cluster)

f = 'map_station_cluster.html'
map.save(f)
map
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? Please include a full traceback. Also, in these situations, I always recommend checking the shapes of all relevant pandas data and numpy arrays. This type of problem is commonly an error with array shape and may require a simple call to `array.squeeze` or `array.reshape`.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/folium/utilities.py in validate_locations(locations)
     88     try:
---> 89         float(next(iter(next(iter(next(iter(locations)))))))
     90     except (TypeError, StopIteration):

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/folium/utilities.py in validate_location(location)
     49     if len(location) != 2:
     50         raise ValueError('Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, '
---> 51                          'instead got: {!r}.'.format(location))
     52     try:
     53         coords = (location[0], location[1])

ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got: 0         39.036270
1         39.277840
2         39.086688
3         39.086688
4         39.198295
            ...    
318012    39.150550

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that when you use the raw dataframe data as input to the `MarkerCluster` function, you are getting an unwanted id/index column. I would say, convert to a Numpy array and remove this column if it's still there (you can check by printing df.Lattitude.to_numpy().shape).